# Please, how I can get with FireMonkey if screen is on or off on iOS device?

Tags: ios, firemonkey

I'm developing an App for iOS with Firemonkey (Delphi) that can run in background mode, but sometimes I need to know if device is in sleep mode, or with screen on or off (it also serves me).

Please, any suggestions?.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From these constants you can get the App state (Active, Inactive and background)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/state.

Comment: Thanks Kishan Kumar, but I can know throw TApplicationEvent if my App is running on foreground or background. I need to know if device (phone) is in sleep mode, or have screen off. The App state fires with "background" when user changes to another App or back to device main screen. I want to know if device screen is off (or sleep mode).